# in constructor 'cout' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, cout

i wanted to practise some basic c++ stuff. I focused on inheritance just to experiment with that. Everything went well until i faced some strange problem: 'cout' was not declared in this scope. I have looked on some topics but on most of them the hints were like append  library or write 'using namespace std' but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
#include <iostream>

class podst
{
public:
    float a;
    float b;
    float dodaw();
    podst(float c,float d) : a(c), b(d)
    {

    }
};
float podst::dodaw()
{
    return (a+b);
}

class poch : public podst
{
    poch() : podst(5,4)
    {
       cout << a << endl << b << dodaw() << endl;
    }

};


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    podst podst(1,2);
    cout <<  podst.dodaw() << endl;
    poch poch2;

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: It's much better to utilize `std::cout` instead of `using namespace std;` at all.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poch` calls `cout` from global namespace, not from `std` namespace. Notice that `using namespace std;` directive is actually below it, not above. If you don't want to write whole namespace prefix every time it would be better to place that directive on per-function basis, rather then per-file basis:

```
poch() : podst(5,4)
{
   using namespace std;
   cout << a << endl << b << dodaw() << endl;
}
```

This approach will help to keep large code bases in piece.

Comment: I'm curious why you chose `using namespace std;` in the constructor body as your suggested solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I suggested to utilize that directive on per-function basis, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

the using namespace std is below the first time you use    cout.
try using    std::cout and    std::endl in the poch class.

Comment: +1. And, even better, instead of using `std::endl`, use `'\n'`. This code doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit the standard library namespace caller ::std, you should write

```
using namespace std;
```

before (usually written right after #include statements and before int main()"

```
cout << ...
```

as the compiler reads the code sequentially. Note that it is considered bad practice to use 'using'. I recommend getting used to using with the std:: namespace caller as such:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

To fix your specific problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class podst { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A using declaration starts to take effect at the point where you write it. Since the call to `cout` is above that point it isn’t covered by the `using` and you’ll have to spell out `std::cout` there.

[You should avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). A better alternative is to only pull in what you need, e.g. with `using std::cout;`. But the even better choice is to just use the qualified names. It’s a bit more to type, but it prevents ambiguity; and the qualified names are so ubiquitous in every code base I’ve seen that – at least to me – an unqualified name like `cout` is always a bit surprising and trips me up slightly when reading code.

Answer (score 0):

well since poch is a class inheriting from a parent class you needed to either
declare the standard namespace at the beginning of the file to make it global to all classes and functions but you declared it before main so the poch class was not able to make use of it, rather you could have explicitly used std::cout and std::endl and the program would have no trouble compiling.

Comment: I've recommended your other answer to be deleted. If you have more content to add, use the "Edit" button to edit an existing answer and improve on it, rather than create multiple answers to a single question.

Answer (score 0):

```
class poch : public podst
{
    poch() : podst(5,4)
    {
       //you should have used std::cout
       std::cout << a << endl << b << dodaw() << std::endl;
    }

};
```

Comment: please delete / move this answer into your other answer.